# A sequence of positive finite measures has a positive measure in the weak limit.

Tags: measure-theory, weak-convergence

I think the statement in the header is true, but I haven't been able to find a proof for it. Consider the measurable space $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$, i.e. the real number line with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Let $(\nu_n)_n$ be a sequence of positive finite measures on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$, having the weak limit $\nu$. In symbols

\begin{align}
\lim_{n \rightarrow\infty}\bigg|\int_\mathbb{R} f(y) (\nu_n - \nu)(dy) \bigg| = 0
\end{align}

for each bounded continuous function $f$. I want to prove that $\nu$ is a positive measure (yes, I have assumed that $\nu$ is in fact a measure. Is this true?), namely that

\begin{align}
\nu(B) \geq 0
\end{align}

for each $B \in \mathcal{B}$.

**Solution idea:**

Aiming for a contrdiction, assume that there is a Borel set $B$ such that $\nu(B) < 0$. Find a continuous function $f_K$ with $B$ in its support such that $f_K = K$ in $B$ and $f_K = 0$ except on $\mathcal{N}_B$, some neighbourhood of $B$. Then use the definition to show that for each $\epsilon > 0$ one can find $K$ such that

\begin{align}
\lim_{n \rightarrow\infty}\bigg|\int_\mathbb{R} f_K(y) (\nu_n - \nu)(dy) \bigg| = \lim_{n \rightarrow\infty}\bigg|\int_{\mathcal{N}_B} f_K(y) (\nu_n - \nu)(dy) \bigg| \geq \epsilon.
\end{align}

This would contradict the weak convergence, and hence settling the statement.

**Problems**

- I need $f_K$ to go to zero ''fast enough'' outside $B$, while still being continuous.
- It seems difficult to show explicitly that the above inequality holds.

Comment: Apply Liouville's principles. Any measurable step function can be approximated by a continuous function in $L^1$ norm.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is certainly true that one can approximate the Lebesgue integral of simple functions by the Lebesgue integral of continuous functions. It is not clear to me that this will work for $\nu$.

Further thoughts: In search for a contradiction I assumed that $\nu$ was a signed measure. Then, by the Jordan decomposition $\nu = \nu^+ - \nu^-$ we get

\begin{align}
\int_\mathbb{R} f_K(y) (\nu_n - \nu(dy)) = \int_{\mathcal{N}_B \setminus B } f(y) (\nu_n - \nu^+)(dy) + K (\nu_n + \nu^-)(B)
\end{align}

One could possibly work from here..

Comment: Positivity of a measure is equivalent to the integrals of nonnegative continuous functions being nonnegative (Riesz representation). This property is preserved by weak convergence.

Comment: @1999  Thank you for your answer! Can you elaborate a bit more?

If I understood you correctly, the statement

\begin{align}
\Big( \int f \nu \geq 0 \forall f \in C(\mathbb{R}), f \geq 0 \Big) \Leftrightarrow \nu \geq 0
\end{align}

is true. If it is true, my solution idea will work. However, I don't see the relation to any Riesz representation, nor that it is preserved by weak convergence. Can you provide any sources or give more information? Thanks again!